# frames html and ajax

Tags: html, ajax

I have 3 frames in a html page. In one frame, i am sending ajax request. Now I want to update the data sent by server in other frame. Is it possible

Comment: Arte both frames in the same domain?

Comment: yes they are in the same domain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If those frames are on the same domain [here's an example](http://www.irt.org/script/53.htm) how to call function from one frame to another. So once the AJAX request completes in the first frame you could call a javascript function on the second frame which will take care of updating the contents. If the frames are not on the same domain this is not permitted for security reasons.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? Please leave a comment when downvoting.

Answer (score 2):

Of course this is possible.
From the iframe you can access the parent windows using the 'parent' object.
so from the 'frame1' you can write
parent.getElementById('frame2').contentDocument.getElementById('id of the control in frame2')